# Наименование процесса распределения знаний по отделам

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как назвать деление знаний по разделам?Каждый раздел будет освещать предмет с определенной точки зрения или определенное свойство его. Практические, теоретические аспекты, особенности функционирования, применение предмета.

Классификация
Типология
Рубрикация

Comment: Правильно не "типология" (результат), а "типизация" (процесс).

Comment: На самом деле мне и был нужен результат (типизации). Мне было интересно, как назвать распределение по завершении процесса.

Comment: Классификация/типизация - это распределение объектов, понятий по классам/типам, которые уже давно существуют в науке. То есть не по любым названиям. То, что вам нужно, это систематизация (в узком смысле - в мыслях) и рубрикация (в широком - разделы в работе).

Answer (score 1):

Типизация - процесс деления на типы.

Типология - это общепринятый результат типизации, критерии.

Типологизация - название метода сортировки делением на типы.

Comment: То есть разделы науки будут называться "Типами"? Речь идет именно о классификации научных знаний, исследований.

Comment: Разделы науки не называют типами. Например: типы самолётов, типы характера.

Comment: Часто разделами науки являются другие "поднауки".

Comment: Разделы науки - это больше категории. Сюда больше подходит общее слово "классификация". И знания обычно именно классифицируются. Слово "типы" используется для конкретных понятий, предметов: типы темперамента, типы подводных лодок. Слово "наука" слишком объёмное, чтобы делиться на типы. Элементы науки делятся на типы. Например типы растений в биологии.

Comment: Интересна была даже в первую очередь вспомогательная классификация: наименования разделов, на которые делит учёный - исследователь свою работу. Например: сейчас я буду заниматься таким разделом своих исследований по психологии поведения, как "Жесты и мимика".

Comment: В общем слово типы применяется для чего-то конкретного. Слова "наука" и "знания" слишком объёмные для этого. По этой причине "типы науки" очень не звучит. В курсовых работах так и пишут "Раздел I, Раздел II". А именно деление знаний по разделам корректно назвать "распределением информации".

Comment: Нашёл точный ответ на вопрос в словаре. **Рубрикация - деление текста на разделы, части, главы, параграфы и т. п**.

Comment: Это слово, наверное, в этом значении применимо главным образом в типографском деле

Comment: В другом словаре это **распределение по рубрикам, разделам**. То есть именно сам процесс. Учёный распределяет имеющийся у него материал, данные своих исследований посредством рубрикации. То есть не пишет обо всём вперемешку. Типографское дело - это просто результат.

Comment: В этом смысле отдел знаний в общем числе знаний может называться рубрикой. И исследователь возвращается к рубрикам, дополняет их.

Comment: Не обязательно рубрикой, а любой единицей: разделом, частью, главой, параграфом. То есть под рубрикацией подразумевается систематизация знаний, только в широком смысле.

Comment: То есть учёный, занимаясь мыслительной деятельностью (даже и не составляя труд) занимается рубрикацией собственных размышлений, суждений.

Comment: Это правильнее назвать систематизацией (упорядочивание размышлений и данных в одну связанную систему). А рубрикация - это просто распределение информации по разделам. То есть это общая систематизация структуры научной работы.

Answer (score 0):

Детализация, отсортирование, рассортировывание.